# moving files with keeping the files that have the same name

Tags: batch, batch-file

I’m trying to move files to a directory. I want like, if there is a file with the same name then add number to it or something like that, I want to keep both of them:-

```
move C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\*.jpg C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\photo\*
```

For example, What I want after moving the files:

```
test.jpg    
test(1).jpg    
test(2).jpg    
scot.jpg    
scot(1).jpg
scot(2).jpg
```

Comment: You probably need to explore using a [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop and adding some [`IF EXIST`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic to append the incremented number and such. Maybe incorporate in some [`SET /A var+=1`](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-2-variables.html) logic too. Don't forget about [`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) too but there's a starting point for you so get to researching and testing and then [edit] what you have that you are having trouble with.

Comment: I generally have to write a app to do this. I'd probably use C#, but Powershell or Python are a good option if you want somthing "scripty".

Comment: Powershell will certainly be the way to go if you do not want to use native batch commands unless you are an application developer and understand other scripting languages such as Python and/or C# as those are really robust but for the non-app developer type understanding, try something with a `for` loop as I suggested or try PowerShell which is also rather robust and likely easier for non-programmer to understand logic wise than C# or Python but anything is possible.

Comment: Answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251790/6811411)